# Why some cuts my transition is small

Tags: davinci-resolve

In most of the places my Cross Dissolve transition is of normal size, but at one place it is small size, any idea why ?

Small Size

[image: Small Size]

Normal Size

[image: Normal Size]

Comment: Do you have enough 'spare' at the ends of the clips?

Comment: Try the beginner's tutorials: To fade you need some "material at the ends". So maybe trim the beginnings and ends, respectively.